# RMarkdown: How to embed an 3D plot?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, rgl

How to embed 3D plot (rgl) into a html created via knitr?

There are several older posts looking for similar outcome. However, when I run all the sample codes i found. The rgl-plot don´t get embedded into the html created with knitr, but appears in an external window while "knitting" and disappears when the html page appears.

What I´m looking for is a way to integrate the 3D plot into the resulting html. I don´t mind whether it remains interactive or becomes static.

The following example is taken from the R Markdown Cookbook: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/rgl-3d.html

---

````
title: Embed 3D plots with rgl
output: html_document
---

Set up a hook to save **rgl** plots:

```{r, setup}
library(rgl)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
```

See if it works for this 3D plot after we enable the hook
via the chunk option `webgl = TRUE`:

```{r, test-rgl, webgl=TRUE}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did should work, but it's not the best way to embed `rgl` graphics in a document.

The simplest way is to make a call to `rglwidget()` where you want the current plot inserted.  You can also use `options(rgl.useNULL=TRUE)` to suppress the separate window that `rgl` creates when it plots.  For example,

````
---
title: Embed 3D plots with rgl
output: html_document
---

No need for a hook with `rgl` version >= 0.96.0, just call `rglwidget()`.

```{r, setup}
options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE) # Suppress the separate window.
library(rgl)
```

See it work for this 3D plot without the hook:

```{r}
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))
rglwidget()
```
````

Version 0.102.21 or newer of `rgl` makes it even simpler:  `rgl` plots can be made to appear under almost the same rules as base graphics plots, with just a call to `rgl::setupKnitr(autoprint = TRUE)` at the beginning.

I said what you tried should work, and it does for me.  Why not for you?  It's hard to guess what went wrong, but the most likely thing is probably that your web browser doesn't have WebGL enabled, or you're using some old version of R or `rgl` that has a bug in it.  One simple workaround for a bad browser is to switch to a static plot; you could do that with your code by changing `hook = hook_webgl` to `hook = hook_rgl`.

Comment: `rglwidget()` works fine. great! still could not figure out why the other way didn´t work for me. browser settings seem to be ok. problems with rgl are familiar to me, my used versions might be a cause. any way thanks for your answer

Comment: Is it possible to increase the size of the window in the output file? I have a 3D rgl plot whose axis labels are small (bcz the number of labels are large). The 3D plot has to be zoomed in to clearly visualize the lables. However, before the figure has been zoomed in to allow for visibility of the labels, the lables have gone out of the window box. Neither did I find a way to translate the 3D plot so that I can center the label of interest in the center for zooming in. Any solutions?

Comment: @Patrick:  The current version of `rglwidget()` respects the `fig.width` and `fig.height` settings in `knitr`; that's the best way to change the size.  There are also `width` and `height` arguments to `rglwidget()`, but those may interact in bad ways with the `knitr` settings.